# JSoup: How to remove an element from a Form?

Tags: java, jsoup

I use jsoup for parsing html page and submit form. I need to remove "Back" button before submit form. I use `element.remove()` method, but then I see that `form.formData()` has not changed. Requested element has removed from `form.children()` but exists in `form.elements()`. Is this a bug or I use wrong way to remove element from form?

```
public class JsoupCheck {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String html = "<html><body><form action=\"demo\">"
                + "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"buttonSave\" value=\"Save\">"
                + "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"buttonBack\" value=\"Back\">"
                + "<select name=\"selection\">"
                + "  <option value=\"value1\">Value 1</option>"
                + "  <option value=\"value2\" selected>Value 2</option>"
                + "  <option value=\"value3\">Value 3</option>"
                + "</select>"
                + "</form></body></html>";
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
        FormElement form = (FormElement) doc.select("form").first();
        Element e = form.select("form").first();

        System.out.println("=== Original content of form");
        System.out.println(e);
        System.out.println("=== Original content of form.formData()");
        for (Connection.KeyVal i : form.formData()) {
            System.out.println(i.key() + "=" + i.value());
        }
        System.out.println("form.elements().size() = " + form.elements().size());
        System.out.println("form.children().size() = " + form.children().size());

        e.select("input[name=buttonBack]").remove();
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("=== Content of form after remove buttonBack (result: buttonBack removed)");
        System.out.println(e);
        System.out.println("=== Content of form.formData() after remove buttonBack (result: buttonBack exist)");
        for (Connection.KeyVal i : form.formData()) {
            System.out.println(i.key() + "=" + i.value());
        }
        System.out.println("form.elements().size() = " + form.elements().size());
        System.out.println("form.children().size() = " + form.children().size());
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
=== Original content of form
<form action="demo">
 <input type="submit" name="buttonSave" value="Save">
 <input type="submit" name="buttonBack" value="Back">
 <select name="selection"> <option value="value1">Value 1</option> <option value="value2" selected>Value 2</option> <option value="value3">Value 3</option></select>
</form>
=== Original content of form.formData()
buttonSave=Save
buttonBack=Back
selection=value2
form.elements().size() = 3
form.children().size() = 3

=== Content of form after remove buttonBack (result: buttonBack removed)
<form action="demo">
 <input type="submit" name="buttonSave" value="Save">
 <select name="selection"> <option value="value1">Value 1</option> <option value="value2" selected>Value 2</option> <option value="value3">Value 3</option></select>
</form>
=== Content of form.formData() after remove buttonBack (result: buttonBack exist)
buttonSave=Save
buttonBack=Back
selection=value2
form.elements().size() = 3
form.children().size() = 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FormElement` is a special kind of node. Besides maintaining a list of all children (inherited from `Node`), it holds a second internal list of all  elements within the form.

```
public class FormElement extends Element {
    private final Elements elements = new Elements();
    ...
}
```

When you call `Node#remove` on a child, it updates the parent's list of children, not the internal list.

Therefore, to really remove an element, you also need to remove it from this internal list:

```
e.select("input[name=buttonBack]").remove();
form.elements().removeIf(e -> e.attr("name").equals("buttonBack"));
```